# importar fonte gotham book com css

Tags: css

Estou tentando importar a fonte gotham-book, ela está na pasta fonts/GOTHAM-BOOK.ttf, porém apesar de eu tentar importar não muda em nada.
 Como posso fazer isto?

```
.table td{
    border: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    src: url('fonts/GOTHAM-BOOK.ttf');
    font: 'Gotham Book', Gotham-Book, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está tentando importar a fonte da maneira errada, primeiro você tem que definir um `font-face` na sua folha de estilos, e depois usá-lo:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontName';
  src: url('../fonts/font-name-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0');
  src: url('../fonts/font-name-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.3.0') format('embedded-opentype'), 
        url('../fonts/font-name-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0') format('woff2'), 
        url('../fonts/font-name-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0') format('woff'), 
        url('../fonts/font-name-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Depois é só usar como qualquer outra fonte:

```
.table td {
    font-family: "FontName", sans-serif;
}
```

E [nesse site](http://fontsforweb.com/font/show?id=10146) você pode baixar a *Gotham Book* pra web com o estilo css pronto pra usar.

<sub>*** Note que "FontName" é só um nome de exemplo e você deverá substituí-los pelos seus arquivos webfont.**</sub>